# How to know if a file/directory is hidden in programming in C

Tags: c, unix

I am creating a function in C that simulates "ls -li" behaviour, so i have to know if a file or directory is hidden for not showing it.

Thank you

Comment: What makes a file hidden?  Once you know that, coding to that should be easy...  (As a hint, try `ls -a` some day, and see if you can figure it out.)

Comment: Isn't it just determined by whether the name starts with a `'.'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden"? In UNIX and Linux, there is generally not a "hidden" flag, but instead any file or directory whose name has a leading `.` character is considered "hidden." For other file attributes, `man stat -s 2` has some good information.

Comment: On what operating system? basically your OS will both determine and provide APIs for this.

Comment: voting to close because, it matters which unix, and what is displaying the files.. and also because you clearly didn't do any research to find out on your own, or if you did you didn't include what you were still unclear about.

Comment: my mistake was quite stupid. I was comparing filename[0]=="."; but "." is a string. However, I thought there was a function to know if a file is hidden, something like stat()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, hidden files have a `.` at the start of their name.

Check whether the first character of the filename is `.`; if it is `.` then that is a hidden file and you will not display that file.

```
char *filenames[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (filenames[i][0] != '.')
        // Display filename
```

Comment: Ok, you're right. I was comparing filename[0]=="."; but "." is a string.Thank you very much, i appreciate

Comment: You need to compare characters only. `filenames[i][0]!='.'` compares first character of filename against character `.`

Answer (score 2):

By convention hidden files begin with a dot (.).  ls -a will show them.  But normal ls doesn't.
Modern file systems have extended attributes (xttr) that can make the file hidden.
Here's an example
http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/xattr/xattr_view.c.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the first character of the filename is a dot. Filenames starting with `.` are by convention considered "hidden" in Unix, in the sense that `ls` with `-a` or `-A` doesn't show them.